# Getting a value out of registered variable in Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

So, I'm provisioning an EC2 instance using the `ec2` module. At the end I'm using `register: ec2info`, so, I can later reference values inside, such as instance ID and Public DNS.

```yaml
- name: Print the results
  debug:
    var: ec2info
```

Gets me

```
TASK [Print the results] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {                                                                                                                            
    "ec2info": {                                                                                                                                
        "changed": true,                                                                                                                        
        "deprecations": [                                                                                                                       
            {                                                                                                                                   
                "collection_name": "amazon.aws",                                                                                                
                "msg": "The 'ec2' module has been deprecated and replaced by the 'ec2_instance' module'",                                       
                "version": "4.0.0"                                                                                                              
            }                                                                                                                                   
        ],                                                                                                                                      
        "failed": false,                                                                                                                        
        "instance_ids": [                                                                                                                       
            "i-0e9de15eb82eda3ad"                                                                                                               
        ],                                                                                                                                      
        "instances": [                                                                                                                          
            {                                                                                                                                   
                "ami_launch_index": "0",                                                                                                        
                "architecture": "x86_64",                                                                                                       
                "block_device_mapping": {                                                                                                       
                    "/dev/sda1": {                                                                                                              
                        "delete_on_termination": true,                                                                                          
                        "status": "attached",                                                                                                   
                        "volume_id": "vol-066bb2dd4d14bdcac"                                                                                    
                    }                                                                                                                           
                },                                                                                                                              
                "dns_name": "ec2-35-173-126-60.compute-1.amazonaws.com",                                                                        
                "ebs_optimized": false,                                                                                                         
                "groups": {                                                                                                                     
                    "sg-0a732c6cbeb3f1025": "launch-wizard-39"                                                                                  
                },                                                                                                                              
                "hypervisor": "xen",                                                                                                            
                "id": "i-0e9de15eb82eda3ad",                                                                                                    
                "image_id": "ami-06644055bed38ebd9",                                                                                            
                "instance_type": "t2.micro",                                                                                                    
                "kernel": null,                                                                                                                 
                "key_name": "daro.io",                                                                                                          
                "launch_time": "2022-02-01T02:05:22.000Z",                                                                                      
                "placement": "us-east-1c",                                                                                                      
                "private_dns_name": "ip-172-31-90-87.ec2.internal",                                                                             
                "private_ip": "172.31.90.87",                                                                                                   
                "public_dns_name": "ec2-35-173-126-60.compute-1.amazonaws.com",                                                                 
                "public_ip": "35.173.126.60",                                                                                                   
                "ramdisk": null,                                                                                                                
                "region": "us-east-1",                                                                                                          
                "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1",                                                                                                
                "root_device_type": "ebs",                                                                                                      
                "state": "running",                                                                                                             
                "state_code": 16,                                                                                                               
                "tags": {                                                                                                                       
                    "Name": "new_demo_template"                                                                                                 
                },                                                                                                                              
                "tenancy": "default",                                                                                                           
                "virtualization_type": "hvm"                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                                   
        ],                                                                                                                                      
        "tagged_instances": []                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                           
}
```

I would like to get the value of Public DNS I have tried

```yaml
- name: Print the results
  debug:
    var: ec2info.instances.public_dns_name
    ## AND
    var: ec2info.instances['public_dns_name']
    ## AND
    var: '{{ec2info.instances.public_dns_name}}'
```

If you could also point out to the part of the documentation that covers this?

Comment: In general there are 2 areas that help with Ansible.  1st is Python, as Ansible is written in Python.  2nd is Jinja2: the Python template engine which is enabled.  In this case, it's pretty much just understanding how the json gets mapped to a python object.  [Jinja2 filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out

```yaml
var: ec2info.instances[0].public_dns_name
```

Comment: Or `ec2info.instances | map(attribute='public_dns_name')`, which gives you a list of all the public DNS, should you have multiple EC2.